# How can I upgrade my jailbroken iPad?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

I got an iPad 2. With 4.3.3 version, that I somehow managed to jailbreak last year. Im a jail breaking noob, and was wondering, how do I update my current jail broken version, to a later jail broken version, so I can download apps from the app store that require OS 6 or greater

How do I upgrade to the latest jailbroken version of iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way is to wait until the current version of iOS is jailbroken, and then upgrade and rejailbreak - there are applications you can use (a handy range is described at http://www.cultofmac.com/169467/how-to-backup-your-jailbreak-apps-and-tweaks-from-cydia-ultimate-roundup/) to back up the 'jailbroken bits' of the device, but I personally prefer just upgrading and then putting back on those cydia apps that I *really* want on my own - they way I also have had the chance for a bit of a clear out.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful only to update to version 6.2, otherwise you won't be able to jailbreak again.

Comment: I think you mean 6.1.2.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is impossible at the moment because neither 6.2 nor 6.1.2 is signed by apple anymore and there exists no bootROM jailbreak to date for A5 processors. It's only possible to upgrade the iPad2 device to iOS versions signed by apple, or to versions of which the user stored the shsh blobs for his particular device, which I doubt he has.